# Is there a message handler like 'OnPostCreate' for the MFC CWnd class?

Tags: c++, mfc

I need to know how I can access to `GetClientArea()` when my CWnd is created. Obviously, you can't call it before it is created in the constructor and I just want to let the framework handle `OnCreate()` so when should I call it? Is there a `OnPostCreate()` handler or something similar I can use?

Comment: "I just want to let the framework handle `OnCreate()`". So override it, and call the base class' implementation first thing.

Comment: Thank you, that kinda works. Even after I override and call the base class' OnCreate(), the GetClientRect(&rect) is still not giving any values to the rect object. All the attributes are just 0. Any thoughts?

Comment: Show how you override `OnCreate`. Also show a minimum reproducible example, or at least explain if you are using SDI, MDI, how this window is created, etc.

Comment: You'd probably have to wait for the first `WM_SIZE` message after the window is created, before you can rely on the size being correct.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean `GetClientRect()`, not `...Area()`.

You would need to get that rectangle every time the size of your window changes, right? Then the most appropriate place to do it is in
[CWnd::OnSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-160#onsize)